# How can i write this logic?

Tags: javascript, function

I don't know how to display, when you win game,lose or its tie. I know to write logic in condition for each event, but i dont know how to do it in fucntion because i'm trying to bypass repetition.

```js
function ComputerChoice(myMove) {

  let computerMove = Math.random();
  let result = '';

  if (computerMove >= 1 / 3 && computerMove <= 2 / 3) {
    result = 'Rock'
  } else if (computerMove >= 2 / 3 && computerMove < 1) {
    result = 'Paper'
  } else {
    result = 'Scissors'
  }

  alert(`Computer move is: ${result},Your move is ${myMove}`)

  // ------------------------------//

}
```

```html
<p>Rock Paper Scissors:</p>

<button onclick="ComputerChoice('Rock')">Rock</button>

<button onclick="ComputerChoice('Paper')">Paper</button>

<button onclick="ComputerChoice('Scissors')">Scissors</button>
```